# Korean Math Olympiad 2000 (floor function, quadratic mod)

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Let $p$ be a prime such that $p ≡ 1\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 4)$. Evaluate $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^{p-1}\left({\left\lfloor\frac{2k^2}{p}\right\rfloor}-2{\left\lfloor\frac{k^2}{p}\right\rfloor}\right)$.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove that 
$$\lfloor2x\rfloor-2\lfloor x\rfloor =\begin{cases}0\\1\end{cases}$$
(Try writing $x=\lfloor x\rfloor+\delta$)

Then, the terms you are summing are either $0$ or $1$. Check how many times the condition for getting a $1$ happen during the sum using both facts: $p$ is prime and $p=4m+1$ for some positive integer $m$.

This should lead you to the sum $S(p)=2m=\frac{p-1}{2}$.

I am giving you a direction. But you should do some work as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, originally I absolutely had no clue on where I should go, now I kind of get a feeling.